# What's an alternate to using Broadcast Receiver in a Custom View?

Tags: android

I see people not recommending the use of a broadcast receiver in a Custom View because it doesn't have a clear life-cycle methods. However, if I register a broadcast receiver in `onAttachedToWindow()` and unregister `onDetachedFromWindow()`, it works as expected. To achieve a functionality, wherein a custom view in a fragment/activity can change its view state by listening to events sent by another view/fragment/activity, I could only think of LocalBroadcastReceiver.

I don't want to register the broadcast receiver in the parent context (say Activity) of a custom view is because it might be placed in a ListView item with different view state.

[image: Twitter Follow Example]

For example, referencing the Twitter app, a page where you can see a list of people Twitter suggested you to follow. Each row item has a custom button which is displaying 'Follow' at the moment. You choose to go to a person profile and click the 'Follow' button there. You come back to find that the same person in the list has now its button view state changed from 'Follow' to 'UnFollow'.

It's kind of a broadcast that a custom view tells other similar kind of views to change its state whenever there's an event occurs. Using BroadcastReceiver seems to do the trick for now, but I'm not sure if I should notify views this way.

Comment: Part of the arguments against broadcasts in views would be more tied to system broadcasts vs. `LocalBroadcastManager`. The rest of the arguments involve standard GUI architecture patterns (MVC, etc.), where something other than the view (e.g., a controller in MVC) should be the one with the `LocalBroadcastManager` responsibility.

Comment: @CommonsWare If I choose LocalBroadcastManager, am I good to go? I agree with your part of giving the responsibility to handle LocalBroadcast manager to something other than the View, something that comes with its own Lifecycle methods, either a Fragment or Activity?

Comment: Considering a fragment or activity as being an MVC-style controller is a reasonably common approach. There are plenty of people who take other routes, particularly with respect to avoiding fragments. And those endorsing other GUI architectures (e.g., MVP, MVVM) might have different ideas as to what should handle inter-component messaging. However, AFAIK, all the architectures agree that views should be limited to rendering stuff on the screen, not determining what that stuff actually is.

Comment: @CommonsWare So in a nutshell, If I use LocalBroadcastManager, with the responsibility of handling it given to a controller (Not Fragment or Activity)  to achieve this functionality, it will be all good? My only concern is, each custom view will register its own receiver. There might be hundreds of custom views (Say, in a ListView). Wouldn't it just gradually increase the system overhead?

Comment: "it will be all good?" -- I cannot answer for "all". "There might be hundreds of custom views (Say, in a ListView)" -- only if your `ListView` is the size of small building. The point behind `AdapterView` and `RecyclerView` is to recycle views, so there only should be as many views as can fit on the screen, perhaps with some spares. "Wouldn't it just gradually increase the system overhead?" -- the overhead should be proportional to the number of messages sent via `LocalBroadcastManager` or another event bus. It is your job to have as few messages as possible.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using `EventBus`. I work for a large mobile app development company and we live by it. It could handle everything that you are after very easily and it is thread safe. Give it a read [here](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) and let me know if you have any more questions about it.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, I will have to subscribe and unsubscribe for events in onAttachedToWindow() & onDetachedFromWindow() of Custom View?

Comment: You would still have to register it with a `Context`. You could just refresh that specific user/list item in the `onResume` of the list? You could start the profile `Activity` for result with `startActivityForResult` and before finishing your profile `Activity` set the result to be the ID or item index of the profile item, then refresh that item. Then it would change to Follow or UnFollow.

Comment: I'd definitely without any ado do that if it only involved two activities, but the catch is, the 'Follow' button (representing with a profile ID) might be placed at many places of different activities/fragment throughout the application. I guess, it would not be efficient to track down this custom button wherever it is, say if the parent view is ListView/RecyclerView/ScrollView, to change its state. I was looking for LocalBroadcastManager kind of solution.

Comment: Each time the Follow view loads it will need to query whether the user is already following or not. I don't think using a BroadcastReceiver will work. Activities/Fragments will not receive a broadcast if it is paused, and you can only have one Activity active at a time.

Comment: I think Activity can receive a broadcast even when it's in a paused state. Google Docs mentioning the fact that a Broadcast Receiver should be unregisterd in onPause is due to reduce system overhead. Although, it perfectly works in paused state as well. How do we go about EventBus? Can we flawlessly use EventBus (register & unregister) in a custom view?